# How to check if two values exists?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to implement a program (in Java) that check if two values exists in a database (PostgreSQL). This is my problem:

I have an external document that Java reads this values:

```
#  letter_id, child_id, toy_id
18,1,2
18,1,3
18,2,1
```

The first row put into a database this values for this reason: letter doesn't exists in my database and then, insert `letter_id` and `child_id` into `LETTER` (it's a table) and insert `WISHED TOY` (it's a table).

The second row is inserted into the database for this reason: letter exists and `child_id` is the same, but `toy_id` is different. Then, update values to `LETTER` and insert `letter_id` and `toy_id` into `WISHED TOY`.

The third row will fail, for this reasons: letter exists and `child_id` is different and this is not possible, only one child can write 1 letter. It is not possible to add this case because two children cannot write the same letter.

I have this functions that I want use:

```
private Integer getLetterId(List<String> row)
{
    String integer;
    String[] rowArray = (String[]) row.toArray(new String[0]);
    integer = rowArray[0]; //Letter_Id
    return (null != integer) ? Integer.valueOf(integer) : null;
}

private Integer getChildId(List<String> row)
{
    String integer;
    String[] rowArray = (String[]) row.toArray(new String[0]);
    integer = rowArray[1]; //Child_Id
    return (null != integer) ? Integer.valueOf(integer) : null;
}
```

My idea is this:

```
If letter exists {
    If letter exists for this child {
        UPDATE LETTER
        INSERT WISHED
    }
    ELSE {
        //this case  will be return an error because letter not coincide with child
    }
Else {
   Insert Letter
   Insert Wished
}
}
```

Wished is an another table that puts letter and toy_id in case that exists or not letter.

I understand how to implement the first 'if':  (if (rs.next()))

But I think I have problems with this 'if':  if (childId==row.getChildId(1))

So, how can I do it? Any help please?

---

EDIT: Sorry, I don't know what I'm doing bad:

```
    if (conn != null) {

        PreparedStatement selectPS = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Integer childId;
        Integer letterId;

        try {
            String selectSql = "SELECT child_id FROM letter WHERE letter_id = ?";
            selectPS = conn.prepareStatement(selectSql);

            for (List<String> row : fileContents) {
            // TODO Update or insert record from PLAYER for every row in file

                selectPS.clearParameters();
                setSelectPreparedStatement (selectPS,row);
                rs = selectPS.executeQuery();
                childId = rs.getInt("child_id");
                letterId = rs.getInt("letter_id");

                if (rs.next())
                {
                    if (childId == getChildId (row))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Updating");
                    }
                    if (childId != getChildId (row) && letterId == getLetterId(row))
                    {
                        System.out.println("This letter are used by other child");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Inserting values to letter and wished");
                }
          }
     }
}
```

I obtain this error:

> ERROR: Executing
>   SQL ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.

Comment: what a terrible copy&paste ...

Comment: Is not a copy&paste... :( I have more code but I wanted to simplify the doubt :(

Comment: Why are you copying `row` to an array, just to extract a value, e.g. `rowArray[0]`, when you have the [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) method for that purpose, e.g. `String integer = row.get(0);`???? It's a total waste of CPU and memory to copy to array first.

Comment: Your problem with `if (childId==row.getChildId(1))` is that that is not how your `getChildId` method works, so it should be `if (childId == getChildId(row))`, which assumes that the child id is not null *(though it baffles me that `getChildId` even handles null)*.

Comment: I can't modify getLetterId and getChildId because is a part of the statement

Comment: I put extra more information on my question.

Answer (score 0):

After `rs = selectPS.executeQuery();` you have to check if there is any row at all, it means `rs.next()` should be run. I mean you have to move 

                `childId = rs.getInt("child_id");
                letterId = rs.getInt("letter_id");`

after the `if(rs.next()){`